# Comparing stock values in Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I managed to print this website in JSON in Eclipse

> https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/SSE/HYQ.json?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-01-31

As you can see, we have an array in which are stock values of a certain company. The array has a length of 22. For example:

```
["2017-01-27",89.13,87.611,88.18,87.699,750] //Array index 2
["2017-01-26",89.22,87.699,87.699,88.315,190]//Array index 3      
["2017-01-31",86.77,84.312,84.32,84.81,1205]//Array index 0
```

My task is to check which one has the greater values. Like, checking if 89.13 is greater than 89.22? No, therefore checking if 89.22 > than 86.77, no and so on. And then printing out, at which date was the greatest value. The problem is to check that in Java. I don't know how to compare these 3 (not to mention 22)

EDIT: The logic is clear for me, my problem is to solve that in Java. An Example with these 3 given above would be nice.

Here is my code:

```
package query;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Stockquery {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String jsonString = callURL(
            "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/SSE/HYQ.json?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-01-31");

    try {
        JSONObject jsonobjects = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONObject dataset = jsonobjects.getJSONObject("dataset");
        JSONArray array = dataset.getJSONArray("data");
        System.out.println(array.get(2));
        System.out.println(array.get(3));

        array.getString(0);
        System.out.println(array.getString(0));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String callURL(String myURL) {
    // System.out.println("Requested URL:" + myURL);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(myURL);
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        if (urlConn != null)
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
            in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                int cp;
                while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:" + myURL, e);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: I think maybe you are looking for Double.parseDouble(...)?

Comment: so do you need to go through the whole array and find the greatest number and then return that date?

Comment: Yes, it's like iterating through the entire array and then comparing the stock values and printing out, at which date was the best stock value for the company

Comment: Initialize `biggest` to be the first one, and then iterate one by one, compare with `biggest` and save the bigger one in `biggest` (and its date, if that what you're interested in eventually).

Comment: *Never* use doubles for money. Use BigDecimal, or use an integral type and do in in cents (or tenths of cents, or whatever).

Comment: @SHG the logic is pretty clear, but how to do this in Java? Could you give a small example with these 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the method below.

```
private static String getDateWithMaxValue(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
   JSONArray stockData;
   String dateWithMaxValue = "";
   double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
      stockData = array.getJSONArray(i);
      if (stockData.get(1) instanceof Double) {
         if (((Double) stockData.get(1)).doubleValue() > maxValue) {
            maxValue = ((Double) stockData.get(1)).doubleValue();
            if (stockData.get(0) instanceof String) {
               dateWithMaxValue = (String) stockData.get(0);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return dateWithMaxValue;
}
```

And just add the call

```
System.out.println(getDateWithMaxValue(array));
```

in your **main** to print the date with the maximum value at index 1, where *array* is the JSONArray that you already declared.

(Code tested and returned date 2017-01-26, which is correct)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

JSON array's element is a *JSON element*. Since *JSON element* can be a JSON array, a JSON array can contains JSON arrays as its elements.

Something like that will do it:

```
JSONArray array = dataset.getJSONArray("data");

// Save the first array's values
String biggestDate = array.get(0).get(0);   // index 0 is the date
double biggest     = array.get(0).get(1);   // index 1 is the stock price

// Iterate over all arrays and update biggest
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    JSONArray arrayI = array.get(i);
    if (arrayI.get(1) > biggest) {
        biggest     = arrayI.get(1);   // updating biggest
        biggestDate = arrayI.get(0);   // updating biggest's date
    }
}

return biggestDate;
```

Note: Not tested!

- Of course, don't use `22` and other hard-coded constants
- Used `double` for simplicity, use `BigDecimal`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even know that array.get(0).get(0) is possible. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Blnpwr It is possible. JSON array's element is a *JSON element*. Since *JSON element* can be a JSON array, a JSON array can contains JSON arrays as its elements.

Answer (score 1):

Did array.get(0).get(0) work for you?
For me not. I had to parse:

```
    Optional<String> maxRow = array.toList().stream().map(Object::toString).max(new Comparator<String>() {      @Override       public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Double.valueOf(o1.split(",")[1]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o2.split(",")[1]));        }
    });

    System.out.println("Max row: " + maxRow.get());
```

which resulted with the "max" line:

Max row: [2017-01-26, 89.22, 87.699, 87.699, 88.315, 190.0]

Comment: I did not test it yet, but gonna tell you if that works or not. Thank you anyway for your answer, pretty easy to understand